# How to obtain even space between variables in math mode?

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath

When I combine numbers and several variables in an equation, the spacing between the numbers and variables are not even. What is the correct way to display the equation? The red box highlight the "problem"!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

$G$, $P$, $Z$, $R$, $T$ are all some variables.

Default:
\begin{equation*}
    a = \frac{8GP}{ZRT}
\end{equation*}

Small space (\textbackslash!):
\begin{equation*}
    a = \frac{8G\!P}{Z\!RT}
\end{equation*}

Large space (\textbackslash,):
\begin{equation*}
    a = \frac{8\,GP}{ZR\,T}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: images of code]

Comment: TeX adds no space between letters and digits in this context however the font may (and does) specify inter-letter kerns, the spacing around and between letters in text and in math is a choice of the font designer and not generally settable within TeX other than manual spacing, as you show

Comment: This depends a lot on the kerning of the font you are using. So there is no real answer as this could look different in any other font. Semantically correct is your first version. I would just leave it as it is. You can, however, fix it a bit, if it disturbs you or if it makes the reading difficult. This is the work of a good typesetter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX adds no space between letters and digits in this context however the font may (and does) specify inter-letter kerns, the spacing around and between letters in text and in math is a choice of the font designer and not generally settable within TeX other than manual spacing, as you show

If I modify your example to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}
\showoutput

\begin{equation*}
    a = \frac{8GP}{ZRT}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

I get

```
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 8
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10 G
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10 P
........\kern1.3889
........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.......\kern4.06508
.......\rule(0.39998+0.0)x*
.......\kern2.3262
.......\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x22.44447
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10 Z
........\kern0.71527
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10 R
........\kern0.07726
........\OML/cmm/m/it/10 T
```

which shows that there is no space added in the numerator, but the font specifies inter-letter kerns between Z and R and R and T.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In "mathdesign", one can achieve more even spacing, so as you mention, the only solution is to change font, manually adjust spacing or just live the default spacing in "cmm".